# SVG <image> rendering in firefox is off

Tags: firefox, svg, png

Firefox's rendering of `<image>` elements is pixelated. The same image with the same width/height appears nicely as an `<img>`. It also works correctly as an svg `<image>` in Chrome.

Example:

[image: example images]

The left portion is the svg `<image>` referencing a png, the right is a normal `<img>` referencing the same image.

Working example:

```html
<svg height="53" width="60"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">       
  <image  href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png"  width="60" height="53" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>

<img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" width="60px" height="53px"/>
```

How do I make the svg image render properly? I've tried all the options listed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image (`image-rendering`, `shape-rendering`, `preserveAspectRatio`, etc.).

Comment: Seems similar to this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1210100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a bug, resolved in firefox 67.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1534188